# Can you "learn" to wiggle your ears?

Tags: physiology, ear

My friend knows how to wiggle his right ear only, and I tried to wiggle my ears as well, but he told me that I can't learn it, it has to be natural. Is there any study on this, or is it actually possible to learn how to wiggle my ears?

Comment: What part of your ear are you talking about wiggling?

Comment: The entire ear. Does it matter?

Comment: One of my family members learned to do it while bored in church as a child. I don't know of a study, but this would seem to be a counterexample.

Comment: Yeah, some people can wiggle just the top part, I think. I'm pretty sure I taught myself to wiggle my entire ears by standing in front of a mirror and manipulating my face muscles until my ears moved. So, yeah, in my study of 1 participant, there is a 100% success rate of teaching people to wiggle their ears :)

Comment: The problem with the question is, how does one know it's "natural" or "learned"? When does one bleed into the other? Anecdotal case in point: I distinctly remember the day I "learned" to wiggle my ears as a five year old (I can now do both, one, or the other). My older brother wiggled his ears for me, and so for a few minutes I tried to do the same, and was then successful. In later years I discovered I could do only one or the other ear at a time as well. Does all of this mean I learned to do it? Or was it a natural talent I had, but took a few minutes/years to discover?

Comment: @erekaplar: I think the popular understanding is that certain people lack genes that are necessary for wiggling their ears. It's something that you can test.

Comment: @Christian: Just dug into it a bit, and found that it looks like there's a basis to that understanding after all. Not so sure it's testable (yet), but I posted an answer about it.

Comment: @ham and bacon I can wiggle my face skin, which in turn moves the position of my ears, but I can't wiggle my ears directly. Please clarify. Also I re-tagged your question if you don't mind.

Comment: Anecdotally, which is why this is a comment, when I was about 20, I woke up one morning just able to do it.  So I would argue that no, you can't learn it.  You can either do it or not, but this can change.

Comment: Similarly to what Craig and @Kaz tell: I never did it before a moment at the age of 16, when I was sitting in a lesson, and felt how to do this. I think that moment I learned how to do this. Then I tried to repeat it from time to time, and it seemed to me first that it wasn't that easy to repeat it.

Comment: Just like erekalper, I "learned" wiggle my ears when I saw a big kid doing it. It took me a few days to get the sense of being able to control the muscle behind my ears. Later I also "learned" control my ears independently. It felt like some mental exercise other than learning.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, What? How could you actually learn that?

Comment: @Pacerier I described in my comment how it happend (and it explaines what I could mean by "learning"). What do you want to ask me specifically?

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, Please describe what do you mean when you say *"when I was sitting in a lesson, and felt how to do this"*.

Comment: @Pacerier Essentailly, it means: "I was sitting and doing nothing special and thinking about nothing special, and I felt that my ears moved and I felt that I could probably voluntarily reproduce this effect." Then, after some training, I could reproduce more or less reliably.

Comment: When I was on 8th grade my teacher told our class that its a skill pretty much anyone can learn if they spend a week on it. I never tried though.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev, Hmm, what you stated is not at all useful to a person who is learning how to do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Much to my surprise, it looks like this is probably true.

According to [a database on inheritance](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/omim) maintained by Johns Hopkins University and the National Institute of Health, it would appear that [ear wiggling](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/omim/129100) is in fact an [autosomal dominant trait](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/omim/129100?dopt=Synopsis). That means that if a person has at least one dominant version of the ear wiggling gene, then that person should be able to wiggle his/her ears. (If anyone would like a to brush up on dominance, [Wikipedia (of course) has a decent article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominance_%28genetics%29).)

It's worth noting, however, that I could find *no other published information* about this alleged gene. It looks like there's a gene there, but we don't yet have it mapped, and it's not being actively studied.

I did find an [interesting article published by Discovery](http://dsc.discovery.com/news/2006/05/24/earclicks_hum.html?category=health&guid=20060524091822) that doesn't talk about genetics, but rather about the physical mechanism for ear movement (among other aural phenomena). Here's the part about wiggling:

> "The mechanism behind ear movements is sophisticated," said Bastiaan ter Meulen, who led the ear wiggling study.
>
> Ter Meulen, a researcher at Erasmus MC, a university medical center in Rotterdam, the Netherlands, added that, unlike other facial muscles, ear muscles have their own accessory nucleus -- a control area for muscle function -- in the brainstem.
>
> "Compared to animals, especially bats and cats, this nucleus is rather small in humans," he said.
>
> He explained to Discovery News that a muscle involved in eye movement also directly controls ear motion. That's why when we look left or right, our ears slightly withdraw on both sides.
>
> Breathing and swallowing are also linked to ear movement through muscles and neuronal pathways.
>
> Ter Meulen and his team made these determinations after conducting an EEG, or brain wave test, on a 43-year-old woman who lost consciousness and experienced rhythmic bursts of ear movement.

So if we assume that the gene does exist, then unless one has the gene, it's true, one cannot "learn" to wiggle one's ears. That's not to say, however, that a person with the gene is just going to be able to wiggle away. As the Discovery article implies, it doesn't look like it's a movement that comes particularly naturally to humans - it might still wind up being a learned process for some people. Point being, it's entirely possible one can "learn" to wiggle, but it looks like one probably needs a specific dominant gene to do so.

**Edit:** As Fabian let me know, the original study I initially found is freely available online. [The .pdf can be found here](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1601-5223.1949.tb03359.x/pdf), the study is on pages 620-621. Worth noting is that the author of the study essentially gives the same "this study is small and not necessarily indicative of anything" warning that I did above:

> Since the material is small, we must not, however, attach too much importance to these figures. Even if these results appear to indicate dominance with a relatively high penetrance, the results must nevertheless be verified on a larger material before they can be considered as convincing.

Comment: The paper this is based on should be [in the supplemental of the 35th volume of Hereditas](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/hrd2.1949.35.issue-S1/issuetoc#group10), which is freely accessible. The authors seem to regard their findings as very preliminary.

Comment: @Fabian: That is an awesome find. Editing my answer now to include the original document.